# Best Devops solution on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

I am quite new to GCP. My requirement is to implement devops solution on GCP. We are going to use python scripts and bigqueries.
I want to know which is the best cost effective devops solution to implement in GCP?

Comment: Can you define what you call "devops"? So many have different definitions on this....

Comment: Want to automate the build and deployment into production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in CI/CD solution on Google Cloud is [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-build). I like this tool and I strongly recommend it. In summary, you have to define the steps to your build. Each steps are based on container. Load it, use it, go to the next one. Only the /workspace directory is kept between step (which creates some challenge sometime). You can redefine your entrypoint, your env vars for a step,... There is a lot of capabilities and there is a lot of help/tips on Stack Overflow or elsewhere.

For the [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/pricing), it's interesting: you have 120 minutes of build free per day and **PER BILLING ACCOUNT**.

---

I'm not a Jenkins expert, I used it 6 years ago!

The main difference is the GUI and Plugins. You can do all with the GUI with jenkins, with Cloud Build, only the trigger and the jobs running/terminated (+ logs) are viewable on the console. The steps' configurations are only done by code (YAML or JSON file). Plugin are custom workers, but you haven't the same library as Jenkins.

On the other hand, Jenkins need to be hosted on VM, to be upgraded, the VM to be patched. And you have a minimum fee for Jenkins even if you have any builds.

Opinionated answer are difficult, because it depends on many factors!!

Comment: If you compare Cloud Build with Jenkins then with respective to cost , performance , simplicity what is the difference?

Comment: I don't know for the performance (I know that you can customize the number of CPU (1, 8, 16) with Cloud Build). For the rest, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a Platform as a Service (PaaS) solution. There are several options available that can help you easily deploy on GCP. Currently, I use PipeOps to deploy my projects on AWS and manage my infrastructure. PipeOps offers a free plan that allows me to create up to 3 servers and deploy up to 100 projects for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for cloud native then you can look at cloud build and cloud run.
Also, you can look at GKE based which can be triggered either by microservices or composer using below steps.
As soon as code is pushed in GitHub a docker image is created in container registry and that image is getting deployed to GKE using Helm.
Other scanning tools you can use is Aqua Sonar.
Hope this helps.